# Can not plot a 3d bar use matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot a 3d bar  use matplotlib.
I have a dataframe like this

```
In[1]: mf
Out[1]:     1           2          4
        0           
       6N   45.238806   104.102564  16.804965
      12S   25.597015   95.128205   13.156028
      18S   29.689055   76.730769   17.078014
       7S   0.000000    156.602564  20.106383
      12S   25.597015   95.128205   13.156028
      25S   0.000000    151.217949  16.929078
       2S   4.962687    49.358974   32.517730
      14N   0.000000    0.000000    33.386525
      24S   10.447761   71.346154   25.343972
```

I want to plot a 3d bar in the dataframe corresponding position.
My code like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xpos = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9]
ypos = [3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1]
zpos = np.zeros(27)

dx = np.ones(27)
dy = np.ones(27)
# to reshape my dataframe to a np vector
nf = mf.values
dz = np.reshape(nf,(1,27))

ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx,dy,dz, color="#00ceaa")
```

but I  get this error:

```
     15 dz = np.reshape(nf,(1,27))
     16 dz
---> 17 ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx,dy,dz, color="#00ceaa") 

   bar3d(self, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color, zsort, shade, *args, **kwargs)
   2526 
   2527         if shade:
-> 2528             normals = self._generate_normals(polys)
   2529             sfacecolors = self._shade_colors(facecolors,    normals)
   in _generate_normals(self, polygons)
   1771             v1 = np.array(verts[0]) - np.array(verts[1])
   1772             v2 = np.array(verts[2]) - np.array(verts[0])
-> 1773             normals.append(np.cross(v1, v2))
   1774         return normals
   in cross(a, b, axisa, axisb, axisc, axis)
   1716            "(dimension must be 2 or 3)")
   1717     if a.shape[-1] not in (2, 3) or b.shape[-1] not in (2, 3):
-> 1718         raise ValueError(msg)
   1719 
   1720     # Create the output array

  ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
  (dimension must be 2 or 3)
```

Where is my code wrong I did not have thinks, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your df.values like this:

```
dz = np.reshape(nf,(27))
```

such that all arrays have the same shape (i.e. `(27,)`, check `dx.shape`, `dy.shape`,`z.shape`,...).
Also note that (while not required) it's good practice to declare both your `xpos` and `ypos` lists as `np.array` like:

```
xpos = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9])
```